# what is the derivative function log(f(x+y)) with respect to x?

Tags: machine-learning

I have the function of alpha + beta log(gamma((alpha+beta))), I want to calculate the derivative this function with respect to alpha. I need it as a derivative of inverted beta-liouville function with respect to each of its parameters.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zkfrZ.png)

Comment: Can you work with a numerical approximation or do you need the actual analytical solution? If the numerical approximation is OK, doing a (cubic) spline interpolation for example can be much simpler to derive.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please learn to use MathJax so you can write formulas: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: The derivative of digamma is the [trigamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygamma_function).  Use the sum rule and chain rule to complete the solution.

Comment: You can use JAX to compute the derivatives: https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_autosummary/jax.scipy.special.digamma.html

Comment: @PC1 I actually need its general formula not as a values, cause I want to calculate the maximum likelihood with respect to each parameter

Comment: In your equation, is `gamma` just some third variable (after `alpha` and `beta`)?  The other comments seem to think it is Euler's $\Gamma$-function.

Comment: @whuber can you please declare it a bit, in fact the function is: log(gamma(alhpha+beta)), I know the derivative of log(gamma(x)) is digamma, so now the answer is just digamma(alpha+beta)?

Comment: You have neglected to differentiate the additive $\alpha$ term in your (new, edited) expression.

Comment: @GEdgar gamma is not a variable as you mentioned its a Γ(x) function. log(Γ(alpha+beta))